# Error building cordova app Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm trying to build an apk from my cordova app for testing on my phone. But when I'm trying to build app, I obtain 2 error : Command failed with exit code 1.
You can find log file here :http://pastebin.ca/3379979

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: are you building in Release or Debug Mode?

Comment: I tried both. Log file attached is in Release Mode. I obtain the same errors in Debug Mode.

Comment: for Release mode you need to do the Signing of the APk, that can be discussed later, but you shouldnt get the error while doing with debug mode can you add debug log.

Comment: I'm doing : Debug -> Android -> Device.
You can find Debug log file here : http://pastebin.ca/3380635
Thanks !

Comment: just confirming, you attached your device to the system right? and open ur Solution folder , you will find the platforms folder and try to Delete the Android platform and Build the debug mode again, donot run the debug mode just build it

Comment: Yes, device is connected by usb

Comment: Ok folder deleted and build done. And after? Thanks

Comment: Yes build was successfull but I can't find debug apk

Comment: go to bin and in that go to android , you will find the Apk and try to copy that apk to ur mobile and try to install it, the problem you are facing is that your device is not being detected so after building success full it should deploy app simultaneously which is not happening in your case

Comment: Build is successfull but apk isn't in bin/android folder. I don't know if something is generated. Ok understood the problem with debug in device mode, thanks.